# How to connect to a device on network with c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a device on my network that controls a piece of hardware. I can control it with my browser like: http://xx.xx.xx.xxx/setvalue.html?Address_Value_Array={someValueToSendToDevice}

I do not need any form of a response from the device. I'm wondering what is the usual way to accomplish this sort of thing in c#. Thank you.

Comment: depends - the way it looks to me a simple WebRequest will do the job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use a `System.Net.WebClient`:

```
        using (System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            wc.DownloadString("http://xx.xx.xx.xxx/setvalue.html?Address_Value_Array={someValueToSendToDevice}");
        }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed thanks for posting. Marking as answer as soon as the timer expires and it lets me lol